# R: Smaller than operator wrong with dates

Tags: r, date, operator-keyword

I have a dataframe `climdata` with 1 of the columns containing hourly measure moments. The format is "2015-12-30 17:00:00".
With my current dataset, the range goes from `"2015-01-01 00:00:00"` to `"2016-11-15 07:00:00"` and I want to extract the dates from 2015*.

I used this code to extract 2015**:

```
climdata <- climdata[climdata$Meetdatum > paste(2015, "-01-01", sep = "") & 
                     climdata$Meetdatum < paste(2015, "-12-31", sep = ""),]
```

The new `climdata` ranges from `"2015-01-01 00:00:00"` to `2015-12-30 22:00:00"`.
This is odd, because I asked for dates after 1/1/'15. However this is not a real problem, since I need that day anyway. 
The problem is the last part. I need 31/12/'15, but when I use `<=` instead of `<` I get `"2015-12-30 23:00:00"` as last element. Which makes no sense at all. First of all, this element should've already been in the dataset when I used `<` and second, where did the equal to 31/12/'15 go?

*This process should later be automated: I'll have a bigger dataset and the year to be extracted will be chosen from a `selectInput()` in a shiny app.

**I used `paste()` because 2015 will be replaced by the `inputId` later on.

Comment: It assumes you mean 0:00 on that day. Try `< "2015-12-31 23:59:59"`

Comment: of course! that's it, thank you :)

Comment: Relying on implicit coercion to POSIXt variables is not very safe. You should do that explicitly.

Comment: Roland could you perhaps explain this in Layman's terms? I'm currently making a shiny app with some population models. The basic models were already written. I need to improve them (correct here and there) and make an app out of it. I started with the given R scripts but with hardly any R knowledge (and no programming experience whatsoever) I'm learning everyday, but my understanding is still quite limited.